# SQL to get X number of accounts from DB, which could be variable number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server table `AccountAction` which is denormalised. It is a flattened version of the `Account` and `Action` tables, which I'm hoping should be a lot quicker for reporting queries over millions of rows. One `Account` can have many `Actions`, so the table looks similar to:

```
Account     Action
account1    action1
account1    action2
account1    action10
account2    action5
```

However I'm having some trouble getting the information back for a restricted subset in a simple stored procedure.

```
select Account, Action
from AccountAction
where ???
```

What I'm looking for is to get the first X accounts, with all their actions. So this will be a dynamic number of rows. So using the example table above if I passed in 1, I would get 3 rows (i.e. give me all rows for the first account).

(I don't mind that the account name will be in each row - it is pivoted elsewhere)

Do I need to use a ROWNUM or similar to restrict the rows? I'm sure this must be a simpler issue than I've found so far.

**EDIT**

The answers using TOP won't work, in the example I'd be wanting 3 rows returned if I said 'give me one (the first) account'. But how do I know there will be 3? Its dynamic. Also they may not be sequential, what if account1's action99 was at position 55 million in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH
  SequencedData
AS
(
  SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Account) AS account_sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    AccountAction
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SequenceData
WHERE
  account_sequence_id = ???
```

Or, for multiples...

```
WHERE
  account_sequence_id BETWEEN 3 AND 5    -- For the 3rd, 4th and 5th accounts.
```

Comment: This sounds good, although what about the performance over e.g. 100m rows? Its going to have to do the rank on every row first right?

Comment: @finoutlook - It depends.  All that is *actually* needed is to have the data in `Account` order.  Once ordered, the optimiser can just seek out the `Nth` instance of that.  So, do you already have an index with `Account` as the first field?  If so, the data is already ordered and you're only processing the minimum number of records.  If not, add one ;)

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of pre-ordering them. I could do that as part of the sync to the de-normalised table.

Comment: Ah ok so I can add an index to account which will help with the ordering.

Comment: @finoutlook - An index *is* essentially an ordered representation of the field(s) in the index.  This allows the optimiser to search the index instead of the table.  *(If the index is clustered, it means that the table itself is in that order and acts as it's own index.)*

Comment: So assuming the results are in the right order after this, it looks like I could do paging now - e.g. passing in params to say I want accounts in position 5 to 10

Comment: @finoutlook - Yep, but also note that any of the other answers also benefit from the exact same index.  Whenever you're processing that amount of data (or even searching for a small chunk of it) you should index it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM AccountAction
WHERE account IN  (SELECT account
    FROM AccountAction
    GROUP BY account HAVING account BETWEEN *start-account* AND *end-account*
    ORDER BY account
)
```

Explanation: The subquery groups by the distinct accounts (and allows for more fine-grained selection criteria than a simple `DISTINCT`) and returns only those accounts. The outer SELECT gets you a variable number of rows depending on the distinct accounts fetched by the subquery.

EDIT: The above assumes that one can filter by the `account` field in `AccountAction` table; this is usually the case in tables that *join* a `M:N` relationship at DB level.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a SQL-Server function.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks updated my code to use `TOP` instead, with the same effect of `LIMIT` before.

Comment: Post change from LIMIT to TOP - What about if the OP needs the 3rd, 4th and 5th?  I'll +1 when you make that change too :)

Comment: @Dems My answer answers *the* question.

Comment: This initially looks good. I'm wondering if a cte and inner join would be faster than an 'in'. One issue as pointed out by @Dems is that if I add paging later I will need results other than 'top'.

Comment: @finoutlook (1) if the num of rows returned by the IN is low (i.e. less than 300 rows with two fields) the result will be kept in memory, making the cost of subsequent operations negligible (use the visual tools provided by SQL Server to check how the query planner will exectue this. (2) In case of paging just put the `BETWEEN .. AND ..` in the inner query on the sequence bound column, as @Dems suggests in his answer. However you didn't ask for this, and I like to keep things simple and easily understandable ;)

Comment: `account_sequence_id` isn't in the source data, to use this you'd need to derive it in another query.  Also, even if the number of rows in the sub-query is small, if the source is large and not indexed, it will still be slow.  That's the most significant factor, not whether using a `JOIN`, `EXISTS` or `IN`; whether the appropriate index exists.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right
then if u want to select initial 10 rows then use

```
SELECT TOP 10 Account, Action
FROM AccountAction
```

or if u want some initial 20 percent records then use-

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT Account, Action
FROM AccountAction
```

Comment: The OP wants the `Nth` account, where each account can have a different number of records each.

Answer (score 0):

did you try TOP?

```
 declare @hoW_many int
 set @hoW_many = 10

 select top (@hoW_many)  * 
 from AccountAction
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the `first N rows`, the OP wants the `Nth Account`, where each account has a different number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

A simple sub-select with `top` keyword (and distinct), would give you all actions for first X accounts

```
select * from AccountAction
where Account in 
(select distinct top (@NumberOfAccounts) Account 
from AccountAction order by Account)
```

Comment: You need an ORDER BY in the sub-query else the results can vary from execution to execution.  Then it's the same as JosvicZammit's answer, from 6 minutes before yours *(Where DISTINCT and GROUP BY are interchangable)*.

Comment: @Dems - Answer amended to include ORDER BY; but my intent was not to include a duplicate answer...